# Flutter Drawer and Appbar side by side

Tags: flutter

How can place scaffold and AppBar side by side on flutter ?
something like this :

```
+-----------+ +--------------------+
|           | |      Appbar        |
|           | +--------------------+
|           |
|  Drawer   |             
|           |
|           |
|           |
+-----------+
```

NOTE : with Drawer collapse button on AppBar .
I can not found any documentation or any example code for this .

**UPDATE** like this : (note: this is html & css)
[Drawer menu (side by side)](https://codepen.io/625781186/pen/ZPVdGV)

Comment: Few tricks can be done, would it be ok for single route/scaffold ?

Comment: @MDYeasinSheikh yes it will be ok .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with this widget where red container will be your Drawer. You can use differernt animation with AnimatedBuilder if neeeded.

```dart
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  const Example({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ValueNotifier<bool> isAppbarExpanded = ValueNotifier(false);

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            ValueListenableBuilder(
              valueListenable: isAppbarExpanded,
              builder: (context, value, child) {
                return AnimatedContainer(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                  width: value ? 200 : 0,
                  child: child,
                );
              },
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    isAppbarExpanded.value = !isAppbarExpanded.value;
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                ),
              ],
            ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wowww , Thank you , I learn new feature (ValueListenableBuilder) in flutter .

Answer (score -1):

Try below code refer [**`drawer`**](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/drawer)

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Drawer with Appbar')),
  body: const Center(
    child: Text('Drawer Demo'),
  ),
  drawer: Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: const [
        DrawerHeader(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          child: Text('Drawer Header'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Business'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('School'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Result with Not click menu button- [image]

Result with click menu button (Colapse drawer)-[image: image2]

Comment: I said side by side .